# Find the next number in the below series

Tags: number-sequence

I created this puzzle. Find the next number in the following series:
$$0, 1, 2, 2, 8, 36, 376, 16832, 6948320, 119573019392, 832844372118349824, 99591503127864016598742704128, 82944234799305314358754027827756996410887110656$$

Hint 1:

> What do you observe every 3 months?

Hint 2:

> The number will be really large.

Hint 3:

> $(79, 196.96657)$